# Tracking Offsite Conversions with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm trying to track my AdWords campaigns through to the final conversion. However, the conversion happens offsite, in a separate session. Many of the conversions are being attributed to that external site, where in reality, the referrer was really the AdWords campaign. Currently, Analytics is properly catching only about 60% of the conversions on the external site.

I've implemented this by placing an iframe on the conversion site, and the iframe contains my Google Analytics conversion code (I defined that page as the goal).

Do you know how to cause the ~40% of conversions that get incorrectly attributed to the referring site to be tied back to the correct ad campaign?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Tracking multiple domains](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55503)